# ENOENT error while giving npm install -g firebase-tools command

Tags: node.js, npm, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnJ6A.png)
Shows the above error while entering npm install -g firebase-tools.
I gave jdk 19 path in env error not solved. I re installed node and npm not solved. I re installed jdk not solved. I tried cmd run as administrator not solved the issue. I disabled windows defender that also not solved the issue. Please give me the solution I am using windows 11 os.

I want to host flutter web app in firebase hosting. But firebase tools are not installing.

Comment: Your error logs should be included as text, within code tags, not as an externally linked image. See: [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.